# Saving data at web server

Tags: android

I want to save the data on the web server. I have data in XML format and I know the URL String. Please tell  me how can I send the request and handle the response.

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a FtpClient to connect to the server.
another option is to use (the slightly less used ) upload functions of HTTP requests.

Comment: Remember android is just the sdk you are working with any java code can run aswell. use a standerd java FtpClient class like in this example: http://www.kodejava.org/examples/354.html